# Pass down data trough router link to my axios api call

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I wanted to ask if it is possible to pass data to my methods via router link in vue. I am a beginner who made a .net core api with the help of a youtube video and then call it in a html with vue/javascript. Now I have different components and each one is a separate js file which I don't find very nice because actually in all of them the same thing happens.

For example (html router link):

```
<li class="nav-item m-2">
     <router-link class="btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" to="/home">GM10</router-link>
</li>
```

goes to home compnent which calls the api here and stores the json in chashier:

```
data(){
    return{
        chasier:[],
    } 
},
methods:{
    refreshData(){
        axios.get(variables.API_URL+'Store10')
        .then((response)=>{
            this.chasier=response.data
        })
    }
},
```

Second router link would be

`<router-link class="btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" to="/GM11">GM11</router-link>`

which goes to component gm11 but home and gm11 are the same except in gm11 it says axios.get(variables.API_URL+'Store11')

I would like to use only one js so that the router link "to" is the same for both but depending on which router link you press the url ending changes.

I tried already some stuff from the web but I nothing is really working. I lack of understanding and only the Youtube Video was not enough

Comment: you can add parameters to your routes or use the query string https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: what kind of data do you want to pass exactly?